# T-SQL replace value on select

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select

I have a column (`SERVICE_ID`) in my table where I can have only 3 values: 0, 1 and 2.

On a `SELECT`, I'd like to change those values into English words for display:

```
select client, SERVICE_ID
from customers
```

Currently displays:

```
| John     | 1
| Mike     | 0
| Jordan   | 1
| Oren     | 2
```

I'd like to change the query to get:

```
| John     | QA
| Mike     | development
| Jordan   | QA
| Oren     | management
```

There is any way to do this using only the select?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
SELECT client,
       CASE SERVICE_ID
         WHEN 0 THEN 'development'
         WHEN 1 THEN 'QA'
         WHEN 2 THEN 'management'
       END AS SERVICE
FROM   customers
```

Though I'd have a separate table for `Services` with columns `SERVICE_ID, Name` and join onto that to retrieve the service name.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE `serviceID_lookup` (
    `serviceID` INT(10) NULL,
    `Description` VARCHAR(50) NULL
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;

select c.client, sl.Description 
from customers c 
inner join serviceID_lookup sl on sl.serviceID = c.SERVICE_ID
```